# Radio button group validation inside angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to implement radio button group validation inside angular's ng-repeat.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
  <input required type="radio" value="M" name="driverGender" ng-model="driver.gender">
  <input required type="radio" value="F" name="driverGender" ng-model="driver.gender">
</div>
```

Name attribute should change in each repeat. I tried appending $index value, but it's not working properly when drivers are dynamically added and removed. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: please give fiddle of it

Comment: Use ng-if='driver"M"' similarly for F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found one solution.

```
<div ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
   <div ng-form="radioForm">
      <input required type="radio" value="M" name="driverGender{{$index}}" ng-model="driver.gender">
      <input required type="radio" value="F" name="driverGender{{$index}}" ngmodel="driver.gender">
      {{radioForm.$error}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Now the validation in happening thorugh the ng-form. Radio buttons will be grouped because $index.

Answer (score 0):

In your code all radio buttons will relate with each other, because name attribute of all is the same. You should identify each radio buttons group. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
   <input required type="radio" value="M" name="driverGender[{{driver.id}}]" ng-model="driver.gender">
   <input required type="radio" value="F" name="driverGender[{{driver.id}}]" ng-model="driver.gender">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change name attribute based on index value , can you check out my answer in following link

In controller

```
 $scope.drivers = [{id:1,name:'test',gender:'M'}];
```

In html

```
<div ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
  <input required type="radio" value="M" name="driverGender{{$index}}" ng-model="driver.gender">
  <input required type="radio" value="F" name="driverGender{{$index}}" ng-model="driver.gender">
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/byLRBhUI2Ezc5CofHnPC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Just try this If you need like below

Think their is two repeats in model, then code of the view should be like this

```
<div ng-repeat="driver in drivers" class="ng-scope">
   <input required="" type="radio" value="M" name="driverGender0" ng-model="driver.gender"/>
   <input required="" type="radio" value="F" name="driverGender0" ngmodel="driver.gender">
</div>
<div ng-repeat="driver in drivers" class="ng-scope">
   <input required="" type="radio" value="M" name="driverGender1" ng-model="driver.gender"/>
   <input required="" type="radio" value="F" name="driverGender1" ngmodel="driver.gender"/>
</div>
```

So this is the code for get this

```
<div ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
   <input required type="radio" value="M" name="driverGender{{$index}}" ng-model="driver.gender">
   <input required type="radio" value="F" name="driverGender{{$index}}" ngmodel="driver.gender">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this. But not working fine when drivers are added and deleted dynamically.

Comment: If you adding the drivers dynamically you should refresh the model as well as when you adding the drivers dynamically

Comment: Yes the model will refresh, but the elements are not compiled again.